# Will some parents be offended when being asked, "Is it male or female?"

Tags: american-english, politeness

If I ask the parent about a baby's gender, will it be impolite or not appropriate to say, "Is it male or female?"

Is there any subtle difference, in terms of politeness, among

1. "Is it a boy or girl?"
2. "Is it he or she?"
3. "is it male or female?"

Comment: Don't ask. Don't tell. It's more fun that way. ;-)

Comment: I feel like most countries should have a federal law of some sort prohibiting parents who would actually be offended by this from raising children in the first place.

Comment: Yes, some parents will be offended. No matter how you phrase it. Some parents will be offended at just about anything. In general, just assume that somewhere, there’s someone out there who is quite likely to be offended by your very existence and the fact that you draw breath.

Answer (score 16):

First you would probably ask if the parents know the sex yet, and the friendliest way to ask the question would be to use *boy* and *girl*.

> Do you know if it's going to be a boy or a girl?

*Male/female* sounds too clinical and *he/she* sounds like you're from Mars.

Comment: "...if the parents know the sex yet..." If the baby hasn't been *born* yet, it's a lot less offensive to be unsure of gender. If the baby is born and one still can't tell the gender it can get a little awkward.

Comment: @Ami, you get used to it: my sister refuses to dress my niece in pink, so she's constantly having to correct people who guess wrong. (It doesn't matter how frilly and flowery and feminine the outfit is, people see blue and jump straight to "boy".)

Answer (score 10):

Are you talking about for a pregnant woman or for an infant?  If you are talking about pregnant woman, "Do you know the sex yet?"  is fine.  If you are talking about an infant and are worried about offending the parent that you can't tell the sex, I avoid this by jokingly saying something to the baby along the lines of "You're so cute.  What's your name?"

Comment: What do you do when the parent says "Taylor"?

Comment: Run away and never look back. Simply cut all ties immediately!

Comment: @Karl: hear, hear! (Ditto for Morgan, Riley, Rowan...)

Comment: Hahaha - or Pat - anyone remember that SNL skit???

Comment: @AdamRackis Yes.

Comment: If you have access to the baby, just take a look at the baby's clothes, crib, toys and whatever else you can find. Most likely you can guess the gender from it. And if you're still unsure, take a peek at the baby's genitals when no one is looking. Be sure no one sees you doing this though; the last thing you want on your social resume is "babyphile".

Answer (score 7):

In America, the most commonly heard terminology for the question is

> Is it a boy or a girl?

The other two are quite rare and might thus be deemed inappropriate by some.  Often times on signs and balloons announcing a baby's birth, you will see:

> It's a boy/girl!

Comment: Same in the UK :)

Comment: What if it is an adult foreign name?  How do I ask the question to his/her colleague?

Comment: Excellent question.  For fear of offending, I often wait to hear whether the person in question is referred to as "he/him/his" or "she/her".  But if I really needed to ask, I would probably say something like, "I apologize, I'm unfamiliar with that name.  Is *XXXXX* a man or a woman?"

Comment: @snumpy As a practical matter, when I encounter a foreign name and I'm not sure if it's a man's or a woman's name, a Google image search for that name will often clear up the matter without having to have that awkward conversation.

Comment: @nohat That only works if you know how to spell the foreign name. If it's something like Baatarsaikhan, that might not work.

Comment: @nohat: Ah, good one, I wish I had thought of that! Once I was tutoring this kid called Bartek, and, not knowing the name, I was wondering whether it would be a boy or a girl. When Bartek arrived... I still couldn't tell. The kid was rather androgynous and had a high-pitched voice. In my desperation I made some Latin exercises, in which the right genders of adjectives had to be filled in to correspond with a couple of names. It was a relief when he filled in *Bartek optimus est*.

Comment: We should also be glad that it is relatively easy to avoid genders in English (as it is in Dutch): it must be more difficult in Italian.

Comment: @genesco Good question, ask it as a question-proper.

Comment: @Cerberus, And a Google image search for "Bartek" returns mainly the model Bartek Borowiec, who is also a little androgynous, though clearly male (and hot). http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_azb7-z33VWA/SM1MKJz6z4I/AAAAAAAAW8s/v-90oG7_4hc/s1600-h/07.jpg

Comment: @TRiG: Hah! I would have assumed that this Bartek on your picture was a woman! Good thing I didn't try Googling the name (in fact I had no opportunity, because the kid was sitting next to me—a really nice kid, by the way).

Comment: @Cerebus, Yes, I said he was androgynous. And I specifically picked to most female-looking picture. Others are more obviously male.

Answer (score 4):

Arguably, the most common way to ask expecting/new parents about their baby's gender is:

> Is it a boy or a girl?

The other one is a less common but certainly not unheard of:

> Is it a he or a she?

*Is it male or female?* sounds awkward, especially in this day and age when personal pronouns are used for pets. It would not be out of place, however, to use *male/female* to qualify new or unborn babies in formal and literary contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Some parents will be offended no matter how you ask and some parents won't be offended no matter how you ask.

In general, it's definitely not a good idea to use the word *it* to refer to a human being, as others have mentioned already.

1. *Is the baby a boy or a girl*? (most commonly used and accepted)
2. *Is the baby a he or a she*? (doesn't quite sound right, the usage of *he/she* seems to be used mostly in reference to animals)
3. *Is the baby a male or a female*? (sounds very formal but would generally be acceptable if asked by a professional working with the baby, such as a doctor, nurse, social worker, etc.)

Answer (score -2):

You should never use "it" for a human, unless you are writing a novel featuring a serial killer.

If you don't know the gender, use "him or her", or in the case of the unborn "the baby". "Is the baby a boy or a girl" not "Is it a boy or a girl"

Comment: Hm...I had always envisioned serial killers as being male.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to use "it" for an unborn baby or small child whose gender is not known/is not obvious.

Comment: @Martha: It is but in this day and age there's always that small chance that the parents are sensitive and might not appreciate their child being referred to as an "it" (object/animal).

Comment: @James P, stuff and nonsense. The "it" in "is it a boy or a girl?" is no more referring to the child as an object/animal than the "it" in "who is it?" is expecting an object/animal to be at the door.

Comment: @Martha: I completely agree with you. As I said, there is a minority that *might* take it badly even though this is correct use of the English language. I wouldn't let this change your habits though.

Comment: -1: As Martha says, it is perfectly acceptable to use *it* for a newborn or unborn child.

Comment: Right. It as in undetermined or unconceived (although that is a debate on it's own).

Comment: @JamesPoulson - In this day and age you can guarantee that someone out there is sensitive and will get offended by whatever you say - but then they'll also be offended if you say nothing!

Comment: By far the easiest and most sensitive way of asking: "Is your baby a boy or a girl?". But spoiled with the  assertion that the pronoun "it" is offensive.

Comment: And you think offending serial killers is not at all dangerous when compared to offending loudmouthed sensitive parents.