# Correct pronoun for "baby"

Tags: pronouns, singular-they

Stumbled along the use of the feminine pronoun for "baby". Previously, I've used *it* and singular *they* when the sex of the baby is unknown.

- Is it correct to use the feminine pronoun (she) for "baby" when you don't know if it is a boy or a girl?
- Can somebody please explain that to me?
- Here's an example: "At about 6 months, when your baby can sit up, she'll probably be too big to be bathed in an infant tub" (http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/baby-bathtubs/buying-guide.htm)

Comment: Related:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28618/pronoun-it-for-baby

Comment: Related: [Is “Is it a girl or a boy?” really calling the infant an “it”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159009/is-is-it-a-girl-or-a-boy-really-calling-the-infant-an-it?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Did you consider the possibility that the speaker or author used "she" because they knew the sex of the baby?

Comment: If you stumbled along the use of the feminine pronoun for "baby", show us the sentences and link the page, please. How are we supposed to know when there is nothing? Please edit your question. Voting to put your question on hold.

Comment: Sometimes baby manuals will use "she" for the sake of simplicity, I remember I had one such manual and the pronoun "she" was used almost exclusively.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Why?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would call a baby *it* or *they* until they were born or you discover its sex, after which you then use that appropriate pronoun.

On a slightly related note, intersex and non-binary identifiers struggle with pronoun usage and they have found all sorts of [alternative pronouns](http://everyoneisgay.com/correct-pronouns-for-intersex-people/) ([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genderqueer)) including the English *they and them* and the German *zir*. 
Perhaps this is some sort of blueprint that one could carry over to babies?

Comment: Your personal opinion is a comment, not an answer. Also, your second paragraph reads more like a comment than an answer. Please refrain from posting a comment as an answer. When you have 50 reputation points, you will be able to post a comment.

Comment: Well that's strange, people upvoting my apology for ignorance has gotten me to the point at which I can now comment freely, thank you!

Comment: No, it's the 2 upvotes on your answer that has now given you 50 points. Each upvote = 10 But I'm not overly keen on the link you posted. Isn't there a better one? To notify someone, so they receive a *ping* in their inbox, place @ + username. Everytime someone writes a comment under *your* answer, you will be notified.

Comment: That's what I was talking about, sorry if I didn't make that clear

Comment: I've just read your link and it is all about "intersex" people, not a baby. Anyway, you can copy the essential part such as "they, them, their;  ze, zir, zirs;  ze, hir, hirs" and paste it in your answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've added another link, I suppose not 'everyone is gay'

Comment: Lol :) :) No, not everyone is. We must respect all people's sexual preferences. Hey, well done with the pinging! EDIT: You're saying that these gender neutral pronouns could also be used for babies, am I right? Thanks for improving your answer. Toodlepips :)

Comment: @Rathony Yes, I'd included it for an interesting tangent that could help with the question, next time I will comment such a response as you have recommended

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. The question is not about intersex or genderqueer. It's about how to call a baby and if it is OK to call a baby "she" when you don't know its sex. How are your two links related with the question?

Comment: They're related to one way of looking at the issue, but they're not strictly related